# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python

how do i fix this

```
 finalHTML = finalHTML + readyEntry.HTML.encode("utf8") + "<mbp:pagebreak/>"
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

it says it is based here

```
finalHTML = "<body>" + book_title_text + date_time_text + "<br/><br/><br/>" + head_text + "</body>"
for readyEntry in finalEntriesInHTML:
    finalHTML = finalHTML + readyEntry.HTML.encode("utf8") + "<mbp:pagebreak/>"
```

Comment: This is a case of "explicit is better than implicit." When you `encode()` a string bytes is returned.  You cannot add bytes to a string because Python would have to guess either how to decode the bytes or how to encode the string.  Plus it would have to return one of the two datatypes, one of which you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.encode("utf-8")`:

```
finalHTML = finalHTML + readyEntry.HTML + "<mbp:pagebreak/>"
```